# Update specific value of object in localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update the dataId field of an object in localStorage.
Object:

```
let responseJson = {
                      id: user.id,
                      username: user.username,
                      firstName: user.firstName,
                      dataId: 1000
                   };
```

I am tring using following code:

```
let loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem('user_id');
JSON.parse(loggedInUser).userId = parseInt(2000);
localStorage.setItem('user_id', loggedInUser);
```

Updated:

```
let loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem('user_id');
loggedInUser.dataId = parseInt(2000);
console.log('loggedInUser', JSON.stringify(loggedInUser));
localStorage.setItem('user_id', JSON.stringify(loggedInUser));
```

Comment: You need to `JSON.stringify` `loggedInUser` object when saving to `localStorage`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Yeah I updated my code but still there is no value changed in localStorage

Comment: You're not modifying the `loggedInUser` value, you're modifying the parsed value, which is should be assigned to a variable, and then reencoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can help:

```
let responseJson = {
                      id: user.id,
                      username: user.username,
                      firstName: user.firstName,
                      dataId: 1000
                   };

let loggedInUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_id'));
loggedInUser.dataId = parseInt(2000);
localStorage.setItem('user_id', JSON.stringify(loggedInUser));
```

[image]

Comment: its not working

Comment: Hello @VarinderSohal, what are your getting an error?

Comment: can't assign to property "dataId" on {} : not an object

Comment: Can you update your code by sharing what you have currently?

Comment: Code update has done you can see it

Comment: Replace:  let loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem('user_id'); By: let loggedInUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_id'));

Comment: Thankyou it's working now

Answer (score 1):

In `localStorage`, all values **must** be of type string. So, you have to stringify your object before storing it.

```
localStorage.setItem('user_id', JSON.stringify(loggedInUser))
```

BTW: You should check the `user_id` value before parsing it (or encapsulate in a try/catch).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this and you should stringify it before setting to localStorage:

```
let loggedInUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_id'));
let loggedInUserObj = {...loggedInUser, dataId : 2000}; // <---should be dataId
localStorage.setItem('user_id', JSON.stringify(loggedInUserObj));
```

Note:- You are not updating the `dataId` property but `userId`.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply but your code just added new field not updated current available filed.

Comment: @VarinderSohal oh yes. you should parse the string to object before and then destructure it to update. and one thing in your question you have posted to update the `userId` not `dataId`.